# Blur image by standard average c++

Tags: c++, opencv, blur

I am trying to blur an image without using opencv predefined functions like blur(). I am using standard average and not the weighted average. here is my code but the result is still the same with the input image. this is for 3x3.

```
    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage(argv[1]);
    IplImage* dst = cvCloneImage(img);

    height = img->height;
    width = img->width;
    step = img->widthStep;
    channels = img->nChannels;
    data = (uchar *)img->imageData;

    height2    = dst->height; // row
    width2     = dst->width; // col
    step2      = dst->widthStep; // size of aligned image row in bytes
    channels2  = dst->nChannels; 
    dstData      = (uchar *)dst->imageData;
    int total = 0;

    //blur
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {          
           for (x = 0; x <= 2; x++)
                for (y = 0; y <= 2; y++)
                    total =(data[x-1,y-1]+data[x-1,y]+data[x-1,y+1]+
                            data[x,y-1]+data[x,y]+data[x,y+1]+
                            data[x+1,y-1]+data[x+1,y]+data[x+1,y+1])/9;
                    dstData[i,j] = total;
                    }
            }
```

i think my problem is on this one

```
                       total =(data[x-1,y-1]+data[x-1,y]+data[x-1,y+1]+
                       data[x,y-1]+data[x,y]+data[x,y+1]+
                       data[x+1,y-1]+data[x+1,y]+data[x+1,y+1])/9;
                       dstData[i,j] = total;
```

what could be done?

Comment: A comma operator leads to a very common mistake: `data[x-1,y-1]` is equivalent to `data[y-1]`. Multi-dimensional arrays are represented by a linear block of memory, so you would need something like `data[x-1+(y-1)*width]` (also, are you sure pixels are represented by single bytes?) Also, you should be checking for boundaries, as when x=0, accessing pixel (x-1,y) is invalid.

Comment: There might be padding at the end of rows of an opencv image, so use widthStep to jump to next row. Consider image data type, might be different from uchar! Consider image channels, you probably do not want to blur among different channels. If user pass an RGB image, your filter would blur RGB together. OpenCv stores multichannel images in form 012012012012 (number denote channel id)

Comment: looks like the problem is that you are always calling the same area for blur: try `total = (data[(i-1+(j-1))*width].... /9;` but as mentioned by @riv you need to check for boundary errors so that the array will not try and fetch from a negative location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a complete program that shows how to do it. you have several errors, 1) incorrect pixel access(http://www.comp.leeds.ac.uk/vision/opencv/iplimage.html). 2) blur loop is wrong,you are always getting data from top left 3x3 corner. if pixel access is correct, you should get a constant image in dst.

another thing is you would also need to take care of channel information, the program bypass that by reading in a single channel image. otherwise you would need to do the blur for each channel

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

    IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("c:/data/2.jpg",0);
    IplImage* dst = cvCloneImage(img);
    int height,width,step,channels;
    int height2,width2,step2,channels2;

    height = img->height;
    width = img->width;
    step = img->widthStep;
    channels = img->nChannels;
    uchar* data = (uchar *)img->imageData;

    height2    = dst->height; // row
    width2     = dst->width; // col
    step2      = dst->widthStep; // size of aligned image row in bytes
    channels2  = dst->nChannels; 
    uchar* dstData      = (uchar *)dst->imageData;
    int total = 0;
    int i,j,x,y,tx,ty;
    //blur
    for (i = 0; i < height; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < width; j++) {   
            int ksize=3;
            total=0;
            for (x = -ksize/2; x <=ksize/2; x++)
                for (y = -ksize/2; y <=ksize/2; y++)
                {
                    tx=i+x;
                    ty=j+y;
                    if(tx>=0&&tx<height && ty>=0 && ty<width)
                    {
                        total+=data[tx*step+ty];
                    }
                }

            dstData[i*step+j] = total/ksize/ksize;
        }
    }
    cvShowImage("img",img);
    cvShowImage("dst",dst);
    cvWaitKey(0);
}
```

Comment: i appreciate your answer and thanks for clarifying my errors. this works great!

Comment: i tried trying this for 5x5 by changing ksize to 5 and the divisor to 3 but i got a darker image of the 3x3. what should i change?

Comment: if performance is an issue, you should avoid the bunch of if branches inside 'for' cycles - skip ksize/2 rows and cols at image bordres, and perform the computation. If you need to compute all pixels, compute the border rows and cols separately - with the benefit, that you can use correct scale factor for the border pixels

Comment: if you mean `-ksize/2;`, there is no need to change it. just change ksize to 5 and it will calculate for 5x5 kernel size. similarly for all kernel sizes, only thing you need to change is ksize variable. if it's 25 for instance then result is based on 25x25. the division by 2 is centering the loop. if you change 2 to 3, then it will loop through fewer pixels, and being weighted with bigger kernel size, a darker image is expected

Answer (score 0):

Assume assigning 0 to pixels out of range, the following code should be what you want. The core is `my_average`function, it computes the average of the 3 * 3 window centered at `i` and `j`.

```
for (i = 0; i < height; i++)
     for (j=0; j < width; j++)
         dstData[i*width+j] = my_average(data, i, j, height, width);

double my_average(uchar * data, int y, int x, int height, int width) {
    double sum = 0;
    if(x-1 >= 0 && y-1 >= 0) {
        sum += data[(y-1)*width + x-1];
    }
    if(x-1 >= 0) {
        sum += data[y*width + x-1];
    }
    if(x-1 >= 0 && y+1 < height) {
        sum += data[(y+1)*width + x-1];
    }
    if(y-1 >= 0) {
        sum += data[(y-1)*width + x];
    }
    sum += data[y*width + x];
    if(y+1 < height) {
        sum += data[(y+1)*width + x];
    }
    if(x+1 < width && y-1 >= 0) {
        sum += data[(y-1)*width + x+1];
    }
    if(x+1 < width) {
        sum += data[y*width + x+1];
    }
    if(x+1 < width && y+1 < height) {
        sum += data[(y+1)*width + x+1];
    }

    return sum/9;
}
```